# Mule - Message Splitter and Response Aggregation for a synchronous flow

Tags: mule

I am facing issues while trying the following scenario in mule esb:

## Main Flow

1) Makes a http request to get a payload say in the following format:

```
<result><row><event_key>4457573</event_key><show_title>The Book of Mormon Houston</show_title><venue_name>Sarofim Hall at The Hobby Center in Houston, US</venue_name><perf_date>01/28/2015 12:00:00 AM</perf_date><area>CENTER ORCHESTRA</area><row_desc>XN</row_desc><seat_num>20</seat_num><seat_increment>1</seat_increment><Cost>903</Cost></row><row><event_key>4457573</event_key><show_title>The Book of Mormon Houston</show_title><venue_name>Sarofim Hall at The Hobby Center in Houston, US</venue_name><perf_date>01/28/2015 12:00:00 AM</perf_date><area>CENTER ORCHESTRA</area><row_desc>XN</row_desc><seat_num>21</seat_num><seat_increment>1</seat_increment><Cost>904</Cost></row><row><event_key>4457573</event_key><show_title>The Book of Mormon Houston</show_title><venue_name>Sarofim Hall at The Hobby Center in Houston, US</venue_name><perf_date>01/28/2015 12:00:00 AM</perf_date><area>CENTER ORCHESTRA</area><row_desc>XN</row_desc><seat_num>22</seat_num><seat_increment>1</seat_increment><Cost>905</Cost></row><row><event_key>4457573</event_key><show_title>The Book of Mormon Houston</show_title><venue_name>Sarofim Hall at The Hobby Center in Houston, US</venue_name><perf_date>01/28/2015 12:00:00 AM</perf_date><area>CENTER ORCHESTRA</area><row_desc>XN</row_desc><seat_num>23</seat_num><seat_increment>1</seat_increment><Cost>905</Cost></row></result>
```

2) Transforms that payload by applying some logic to an xml of this format.

```
<listings>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>903</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>XN</rows>
      <seats>20</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>904</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>XN</rows>
      <seats>21</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>905</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>2</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>XN</rows>
      <seats>22,23</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
</listings>
```

3) Splits the messages using splitter

```
<splitter enableCorrelation="ALWAYS" expression="#[xpath('//listings/listing')]" doc:name="ListingRequestSplitter"/>
```

4) Uses request-reply router to route those messages to dispatchIn VM queue

```
<request-reply storePrefix="listmsg" doc:name="Put message for processing">
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="dispatchIn">
        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
            <delete-message-property key="MULE_REPLYTO" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </vm:outbound-endpoint>

    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="dispatchOut" />
</request-reply>
```

5) Second flow which is processing listening to dispatchIn queue

```
   <flow name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow" doc:name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="dispatchIn"/>

        <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Remember correlation">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_ID]" key="cid" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" key="cgs" />
        </message-properties-transformer>

        <logger message="ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Splitted Message : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="api-dev.srwd10.com" port="443" path="inventory/listings/v1/" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" transformer-refs="DOM_to_XML" contentType="application/xml" mimeType="application/xml">
            <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                <add-message-property key="Authorization" value="Bearer 8da2ba50b471958168dfe0d4efd0f428" />
                <add-message-property key="TARGET_HOST" value="srwq12" />
                <add-message-property key="Acccept" value="application/xml" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </https:outbound-endpoint>

        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cid]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cgs]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" />
        </message-properties-transformer>

        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="vm.aggregate" />
    </flow>

    <flow name="ListingMessageResponseAggregator">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="vm.aggregate" />

        <logger message="ListingMessageResponseAggregator - CorelationID : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_ID], CorelationGroupSize : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE], Payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <collection-aggregator doc:name="Collection Aggregator" />

        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="dispatchOut" />
    </flow>
```

6) request-reply outbound configuration pushing the messages to a dispatchOut queue.

I am seeing that only first message gets processed and rest all messages just get into timeout state. Can someone help if I am doing something wrong here. Here is the complete configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd">
    <!-- HTTPS Connection Configuration With CERTS -->
    <https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
        <https:tls-server  path="/Users/rkesara/opt/MULE/truststore/cacerts" storePassword="changeit" />
    </https:connector>

    <!-- List of transformers that might be useful for this flow -->
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer outputEncoding="UTF-8" name="DOM_to_XML" doc:name="DOM to XML"/>

    <!-- Root flow that can trigger pull and push functionality -->
    <flow name="PullAndPushInventoryFlow" doc:name="PullAndPushInventoryFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="Inside PullAndPushInventoryFlow - QueryParams : #[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Invoking GetLocationList API" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="srwq12csb001.srwq12.com" port="8280" path="services/t/telecharge.com/GetLocationList/?eventId=4457573&amp;rows=XN&amp;seatFrom=20&amp;seatTo=40&amp;costMin=900&amp;costMax=910" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Applying bundling logic to create SH listing requests on telecharge payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT" xsl-file="src/main/resources/xslt/listingrequest.xsl" />
        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Listing requests payload after bunlding : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Splitting listing requests..." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <splitter enableCorrelation="ALWAYS" expression="#[xpath('//listings/listing')]" doc:name="ListingRequestSplitter"/>
        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Number of listing requests found after bunlding : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <request-reply storePrefix="listmsg" doc:name="Put message for processing">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="dispatchIn">
                <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                    <delete-message-property key="MULE_REPLYTO" />
                </message-properties-transformer>
            </vm:outbound-endpoint>

            <vm:inbound-endpoint path="dispatchOut" />
        </request-reply>

        <logger message="Aggregated Payload-&gt; #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
   </flow>

   <flow name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow" doc:name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="dispatchIn"/>

        <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Remember correlation">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_ID]" key="cid" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" key="cgs" />
        </message-properties-transformer>

        <logger message="ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Splitted Message : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="api-dev.srwd10.com" port="443" path="inventory/listings/v1/" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" transformer-refs="DOM_to_XML" contentType="application/xml" mimeType="application/xml">
            <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                <add-message-property key="Authorization" value="Bearer 8da2ba50b471958168dfe0d4efd0f428" />
                <add-message-property key="TARGET_HOST" value="srwq12" />
                <add-message-property key="Acccept" value="application/xml" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </https:outbound-endpoint>

        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cid]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cgs]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" />
        </message-properties-transformer>

        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="vm.aggregate" />
    </flow>

    <flow name="ListingMessageResponseAggregator">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="vm.aggregate" />

        <logger message="ListingMessageResponseAggregator - CorelationID : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_ID], CorelationGroupSize : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE], Payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <collection-aggregator doc:name="Collection Aggregator" failOnTimeout="false"/>

        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="dispatchOut" />
    </flow>

</mule>
```

Just to add detailed logs of what is happening:

```
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:15,617 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Inside PullAndPushInventoryFlow - QueryParams : {}

INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:15,617 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Invoking GetLocationList API on telecharge

INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,213 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Applying bundling logic to create SH listing requests on telecharge payload : <result><row><event_key>4457573</event_key><show_title>The Book of Mormon Houston</show_title><venue_name>Sarofim Hall at The Hobby Center in Houston, US</venue_name><perf_date>01/28/2015 12:00:00 AM</perf_date><area>CENTER ORCHESTRA</area><row_desc>XN</row_desc><seat_num>20</seat_num><seat_increment>1</seat_increment><Cost>903</Cost></row><row><event_key>4457573</event_key><show_title>The Book of Mormon Houston</show_title><venue_name>Sarofim Hall at The Hobby Center in Houston, US</venue_name><perf_date>01/28/2015 12:00:00 AM</perf_date><area>CENTER ORCHESTRA</area><row_desc>XN</row_desc><seat_num>21</seat_num><seat_increment>1</seat_increment><Cost>904</Cost></row><row><event_key>4457573</event_key><show_title>The Book of Mormon Houston</show_title><venue_name>Sarofim Hall at The Hobby Center in Houston, US</venue_name><perf_date>01/28/2015 12:00:00 AM</perf_date><area>CENTER ORCHESTRA</area><row_desc>XN</row_desc><seat_num>22</seat_num><seat_increment>1</seat_increment><Cost>905</Cost></row><row><event_key>4457573</event_key><show_title>The Book of Mormon Houston</show_title><venue_name>Sarofim Hall at The Hobby Center in Houston, US</venue_name><perf_date>01/28/2015 12:00:00 AM</perf_date><area>CENTER ORCHESTRA</area><row_desc>XN</row_desc><seat_num>23</seat_num><seat_increment>1</seat_increment><Cost>905</Cost></row></result>

INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,221 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Listing requests payload after bunlding : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listings>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>903</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>XN</rows>
      <seats>20</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>904</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>XN</rows>
      <seats>21</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>905</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>2</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>XN</rows>
      <seats>22,23</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
</listings>

INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,221 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Splitting listing requests...
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,231 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Number of listing requests found after bunlding : 9
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,232 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.521391459'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,232 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.521391459'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,236 [[telecharge].ListingMessageProcessorFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Splitted Message :    <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>903</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>XN</rows>
      <seats>20</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>

INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,238 [[telecharge].ListingMessageProcessorFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,238 [[telecharge].ListingMessageProcessorFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,238 [[telecharge].ListingMessageProcessorFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,238 [[telecharge].ListingMessageProcessorFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'HTTP_HTTPS.dispatcher.1221616365'. Object is: HttpsClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:16,238 [[telecharge].ListingMessageProcessorFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'HTTP_HTTPS.dispatcher.1221616365'. Object is: HttpsClientMessageDispatcher
WARN  2014-06-12 16:00:17,658 [[telecharge].ListingMessageProcessorFlow.stage1.02] org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase: Cookie rejected: "$Version=0; TLTSID=4FE5E730F28510F29E93A683F88FB10C; $Path=/; $Domain=.srwq12.com". Illegal domain attribute ".srwq12.com". Domain of origin: "api-dev.srwd10.com"
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:17,660 [[telecharge].connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.222031696'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:17,660 [[telecharge].connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.222031696'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-06-12 16:00:17,664 [[telecharge].ListingMessageResponseAggregator.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ListingMessageResponseAggregator - CorelationID : 5168ed50-f285-11e3-b82a-28cfe91ad417, CorelationGroupSize : 9, Payload : {"listing":{"id":"1082795830","status":"ACTIVE"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be a correct solution for my initial question to deal with large number of elements in payload but i found a synchronous way to deal with list of requests. I still have to transform the response at the end but atleast the aggregated payload is coming up fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd">
    <!-- HTTPS Connection Configuration With CERTS -->
    <https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
        <https:tls-server  path="/Users/rkesara/opt/MULE/truststore/cacerts" storePassword="changeit" />
    </https:connector>

    <!-- List of transformers that might be useful for this flow -->
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer outputEncoding="UTF-8" name="DOM_to_XML" doc:name="DOM to XML"/>

    <!-- Root flow that can trigger pull and push functionality -->
    <flow name="PullAndPushInventoryFlow" doc:name="PullAndPushInventoryFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="Inside PullAndPushInventoryFlow - QueryParams : #[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Invoking GetLocationList API on telecharge" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="srwq12csb001.srwq12.com" port="8280" path="services/t/telecharge.com/GetLocationList/?eventId=4457573&amp;rows=XO&amp;seatFrom=1&amp;seatTo=6&amp;costMin=900&amp;costMax=905" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Applying bundling logic to create SH listing requests on telecharge payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT" xsl-file="src/main/resources/xslt/listingrequest.xsl" />
        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Listing requests payload after bunlding : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Splitting listing requests..." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <splitter enableCorrelation="ALWAYS" expression="#[xpath('//listings/listing')]" doc:name="ListingRequestSplitter"/>
        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Number of listing requests found after bunlding : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE] - current request number : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <flow-ref name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow" />

        <collection-aggregator />        
        <logger message="Aggregated Payload-&gt; #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
   </flow>

   <flow name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow" doc:name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow">

        <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Remember correlation">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_ID]" key="cid" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" key="cgs" />
        </message-properties-transformer>

        <logger message="ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Invoking listingAPI with request payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="api-dev.srwd10.com" port="443" path="inventory/listings/v1/" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" transformer-refs="DOM_to_XML" contentType="application/xml" mimeType="application/xml">
            <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                <add-message-property key="Authorization" value="Bearer 8da2ba50b471958168dfe0d4efd0f428" />
                <add-message-property key="TARGET_HOST" value="srwq12" />
                <add-message-property key="Acccept" value="application/xml" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </https:outbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Listing API response : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cid]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cgs]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" />
        </message-properties-transformer>

    </flow>

</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for async way of dealing with the issue too..

Full credit to this blog: (http://geekyprimitives.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/fork-and-join-with-mule-3/)

Here is how the async way will work using a request reply router:

```
    <flow name="SimpleFilePollingFlow" doc:name="Simple File Polling">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="/Users/rkesara/opt/MULE/File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="ListingRequestsXmlFile">
            <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.xml"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="SimpleFilePollingFlow - File read successfully and contents : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="xslt/listingrequest.xsl" doc:name="BundleListingsUsingXSLT"/>
        <transformer ref="DOM_to_XML" />

        <request-reply doc:name="Split and process listing messages asynchronously">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="listingRequestQueue" doc:name="listingRequestQueue">
                <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                    <delete-message-property key="MULE_REPLYTO" />
                </message-properties-transformer>                                               
            </vm:outbound-endpoint>
            <vm:inbound-endpoint path="listingResponseQueue" doc:name="listingResponseQueue" />
        </request-reply>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON Array to List" />
        <logger message="SimpleFilePollingFlow -Aggregated JSON-&gt; #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="{&quot;listings&quot;: #[payload]}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

        <logger message="SimpleFilePollingFlow - Aggregated JSON With Root Element -&gt; #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <response>
            <http:response-builder status="200" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
        </response>        
    </flow>

    <flow name="ListingRequestQueueFlow" doc:name="Listing Request Queue Processor">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="listingRequestQueue" doc:name="listingRequestQueue" />
        <logger message="Inside ListingRequestQueueFlow -  payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <splitter enableCorrelation="ALWAYS" expression="#[xpath('//listings/listing')]" doc:name="ListingRequestSplitter" />
        <logger message="Inside ListingRequestQueueFlow -  NumOfListingRequests : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <flow-ref name="ListingRequestWorkerFlow" doc:name="Invoke Listing Request Worker Flow" />      
    </flow>

   <flow name="ListingRequestWorkerFlow" doc:name="Listing Request Worker Flow"  processingStrategy="allow500Threads">
        <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Remember correlation">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_ID]" key="cid" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" key="cgs" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <logger message="ListingRequestWorkerFlow - Invoking listingAPI with request payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="api-dev.srwd10.com" port="443" path="inventory/listings/v1/" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" transformer-refs="DOM_to_XML" contentType="application/xml" mimeType="application/xml" responseTimeout="180000">
            <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                <add-message-property key="Acccept" value="application/xml" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </https:outbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="ListingRequestWorkerFlow - Listing API response for request number : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE], group size : #[header:INVOCATION:cgs], Payload: #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cid]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cgs]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="listingResponseAggregatorQueue" doc:name="ListingResponseAggregatorQueue" />
    </flow>

    <flow name="ListingResponseAggregatorFlow" doc:name="Listing Response Aggregator">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="listingResponseAggregatorQueue" doc:name="Listing Response Aggregator Queue"/>
        <logger message="ListingResponseAggregatorFlow - request number : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE], group size : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE] - payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="false" />
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="listingResponseQueue" doc:name="Listing Response Queue" />
    </flow>
```